# How to reliably install mrxvt on Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04?

Tags: software-installation

I miss it since 16.04, it is very lightweight and has a lot of features!

It still has no .deb for 18.04.
Nothing ready on launchpad either.
Neither on dev's site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20.04
I just installed the xenial build on 20.04 from:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mrxvt/0.5.4-1.2/+build/8903493
with it's required dependency:
[https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/libpng12/+packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/libpng12/+packages)
I used GDebi to install.

---

18.04 (old answer but may be more reliable later)
in short:

download the source file from or anywhere else:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/mrxvt/

read INSTALL to supply deps and:
`./configure --enable-everything --disable-debug`

**install `checkinstall` to easily create a .deb package so you can upgrade it later.**

this command is ready for v0.5.4:

```
make && sudo -k checkinstall --pkgsource="https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/mrxvt/" --pkglicense="GPLv2" --deldesc=no --nodoc --maintainer="$USER\\<$USER@$HOSTNAME\\>" --pkgarch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) --pkgversion="0.5.4" --pkgrelease="MakeRelease" --pkgname=mrxvt make install # see INSTALL for deps and configure command
```

the same command to read it easily here:

```
make && sudo -k checkinstall \
--pkgsource="https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/mrxvt/" \
--pkglicense="GPLv2" \
--deldesc=no --nodoc \
--maintainer="$USER\\<$USER@$HOSTNAME\\>" \
--pkgarch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) \
--pkgversion="0.5.4" \
--pkgrelease="MakeRelease" \
--pkgname=mrxvt make install \
# see INSTALL for deps and configure command
```